# Escape special characters in LINQ contains method

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a problem matching pattern with special characters against some string in DB, specifically this:

```
var titleQuery = this.context.Objects.Where(o => o.Title.Contains("a."));
```

What I want to search is strings containing exactly "a." as substring ("a. sth", "bla a. xxx", ...), but in this query the period character is interpreted as "any character", so I get wrong results. The problem is that I have not found out how to escape this period character or how to change this query to get correct results.

Mapping to DB:

```
Object.cs
---------

public partial class Object {
  ...
  public string Title { get; set; }
  ...
}

MyModel.Context.cs
------------------

public partial class MyEntities : DbContext {
  ...
  public DbSet<Object> Objects { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

I am using MS SQL Server 2008, VS 2012, .NET 4.5, EF 5.0.0.

Any ideas please?

Comment: what result is coming and what is expected?

Comment: What LINQ provider is this?

Comment: If `.` is interpreted as a wildcard, what happens if you try `\.`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: coming: every string containg wildcard "a." (*ab*, *aa*, *auwr*, ...), expected: only strings containing exactly "a." substring

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: the queried object is IQueryable if it's what you mean

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: when I try to escape it with \. then it searches strings "a\." where again period is wildcard :)

Comment: @kolage no, I mean like - what are you querying? A database? (Which)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: yes, it is MSSQL Server 2008 DB

Comment: @kolage with what LINQ provider? LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework? NHibernate? Something else?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: sorry, it is Entity Framework

Comment: This doesn't sound likely in EF, you shouldn't need to escape anything, what version of EF are you using?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: EF 5.0.0

Comment: @kolage there is something else going on there. Please expand your code to include examples of `Title` items being matched in the DB. In fact, it's impossible to use regular expressions in LINQ to Entities (EF) to begin with, the behavior you're describing doesn't make sense on its own - something else is going on.

Comment: @kolage What DB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to keep in mind, that EF is translating the expression `o.Title.Contains()` into SQL. How this is done exactly depends on the connector resp. the database you're accessing (afaik).
If I try this using MSSQL, the SQL reads something like

```
SELECT * FROM [OBJECT] WHERE [OBJECT].[TITLE] LIKE '%a.%'
```

(The "real" query is somewhat more complicated usind parameters and a table alias, but it boils down to this...)

This may have unexpected effects, since the meaning of the `LIKE` operator may differ from the `Contains()` function in C#. One of these effects is that the comparision may be done in a case-insensitive way (depending on the collation used in the DB column).

My guess is that you're not using MS-SQL (it seems to work on this DB...)

You can get the generated SQL using

```
titleQuery.ToString()
```

Then you should consult the documentation of your DB system and try to find out, how this SQL behaves there. I would try to find out, how the period character should be escaped.

Not knowing, what DB you're using, I'm afraid thats all I can say for now ...

Hope it helps anyway :)

Comment: EF correctly implements Contains by escaping problematic characters. If not, this would be a bug.

Comment: I think this escaping is also the job of the connector. For MSSQL I'm sure this works correctly. As for other systems I'm not sure if this is always the case. Also I'm not currently aware of any system using '.' as wildcard, but it seems as some sort of regex comparision might be used. Without further information it's hard to tell what goes wrong in this case...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try to investigate little bit more. I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Then it's indeed really strange :) Usually MSSQL & EF don't shouldn't produce this kind of errors. Check the generated SQL, perhaps this can give further clues what's happening.